# Import Surround SCM to GIT with History information

Tags: git, github, surround, surroundscm

We have large codebase in Surround SCM,
We're looking to move to something more suited to our needs, but getting our history out of Surround is proving to be a challenge.

Googling for git importers, I found that its support for svn, perforce, and many others, but no Surround SCM

So how i need to get all mycode into Git with History?

Comment: Yes, but i didn't find answer from it

Comment: Yet it is still a duplicate question. Whether it has the right answer or not. If you want to raise attention to that question so that someone might answer it, you could e. g. offer a bounty for a valid answer. This often leads to more views and probably answers. As you have more than 75 reputation you can set bounties already.